# angular 2.4.1 on IE10- dont work 4 me

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-10

I was sure that the above will be trivial...
I started from angular2 seed with webpack 2.2 and built an application. when trying to run it on IE10(also IE11 emulation), all i see is a blank page with no errors (chrome works great).
Do i need to do anything else besides including the core-js in my attached package json:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-webpack-starter",
  "version": "5.4.1",
  "description": "An Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular 2 (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "keywords": [
    "angular2",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && npm run ngc -- --webpack config/webpack.prod.js && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci:aot": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:jit": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
    "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "ci:testall": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci e2e:only",
    "e2e:only": "npm run protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "ngc": "./node_modules/.bin/ngc-w -p tsconfig.webpack.json",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/ --host 0.0.0.0",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test:n:lint": "npm run lint && karma start",
    "test": "karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.7",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.20",
    "ag-grid": "8.1.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "8.1.0",
    "angular-gettext-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "angular2-prettyjson": "^2.0.3",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.8",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "elasticsearch": "^12.1.3",
    "elasticsearch-browser": "^12.1.3",
    "fixed": "^0.2.2",
    "for": "^0.1.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "me": "^0.3.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "^2.2.2",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "^2.4.0",
    "ng2-toastr": "1.3.6",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^3.9.1",
    "problem": "0.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "sass-resources-loader": "^1.2.0-beta.2",
    "the": "^1.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.41",
    "@types/lodash": "ts2.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.37",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.0.27",
    "@types/webpack": "2.2.0",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.0",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gh-pages": "^0.12.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "1.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.3",
    "ngc-webpack": "^1.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.0",
    "parse5": "^3.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.14",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "string-replace-loader": "1.0.5",
    "style-inject": "^0.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.2.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "v8-lazy-parse-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~2.0.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Please advise...
THNX

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html), you can add polyfills to your `index.html` :

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

Personnally, I'm using it and add my own polyfills for some functionnality...